# UITableViewCell reuse with custom UIView as a component causing "caching" issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a view which comprises of a UITableView with customised cells - I'm overriding `drawRect` in my custom view.  I've tried overriding UITableViewCell and adding my custom view as an IBOutlet, I've tried not overriding it and just referring to it by `[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0];` both yield the same results.

When I first look at the view, all is fine.  If I scroll slowly, all is fine.  As soon as I scroll quickly the reused cells are clearly not re-drawing because I end up with the custom drawing, being wrong for the particular cells.

The cell configuration method...

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DialogCell"];
MaskedRoundedCornerDIalogCell* dialogCell = (MaskedRoundedCornerDIalogCell*)[[[cell contentView] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[dialogCell setPadding:10];
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
    [dialogCell setAlignLeft:YES];
    [dialogCell setMaskTopLeftOnly];
    [[dialogCell textContent] setText:@"LEFT ALIGNED TEXT"];
    [[dialogCell textContent] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
} else {
    [dialogCell setAlignLeft:NO];
    [dialogCell setMaskBottomRightOnly];
    [[dialogCell textContent] setText:@"RIGHT ALIGNED TEXT"];
    [[dialogCell textContent] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
}
return cell;
}
```

My Custom drawing code in my MaskedRoundedCornerDIalogCell implementation (A class which extends UIView and is added to the UITableViewCell):

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

int maxWidth = rect.size.width - 50;
CGRect container;
if (_alignLeft) {
    container = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + _padding, rect.origin.y + _padding, maxWidth - (2* _padding), rect.size.height - (2*_padding));
} else {
    container = CGRectMake((rect.size.width - _padding) - (maxWidth - (2* _padding)), rect.origin.y + _padding, maxWidth - (2* _padding), rect.size.height - (2*_padding));
}

UIRectCorner roundedCorners;
if (!_maskTopLeft) {
    roundedCorners = roundedCorners | UIRectCornerTopLeft;
}
if (!_maskTopRight) {
    roundedCorners = roundedCorners | UIRectCornerTopRight;
}
if (!_maskBottomLeft) {
    roundedCorners = roundedCorners | UIRectCornerBottomLeft;
}
if (!_maskBottomRight) {
    roundedCorners = roundedCorners | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
}
UIBezierPath* containerBezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:container byRoundingCorners: roundedCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(25.0F, 25.0F)];

[[UIColor lightGrayColor] setFill];
[containerBezierPath fillWithBlendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f];
}
```

The way it looks when I first launch it:
[image: Correct Layout]

The way it looks after scrolling a few times:
[image]

Any advice, gratefully received...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're overriding `drawRect` in your `UITableViewCell` subclass or if it's in a custom `UIView` class. My suggestion would be to do your drawing in a custom `UIView` class and then add that view as a subview of your cell - just in case `UITableViewCell` is doing something in `drawRect` that you're accidentally overriding.

In any case, the reason you're seeing this behaviour is because `drawRect` is only called when the view first comes on the screen or if it's invalidated. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:):

> This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. You should never call this method directly yourself. To invalidate part of your view, and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect: method instead.

In your cell's `setMask..` methods, try calling `[self.customDrawingView setNeedsDisplay]` to invalidate the drawing and force an update.

> You can use this method or the setNeedsDisplayInRect: to notify the system that your view’s contents need to be redrawn. This method makes a note of the request and returns immediately. The view is not actually redrawn until the next drawing cycle, at which point all invalidated views are updated.
>
> You should use this method to request that a view be redrawn only when the content or appearance of the view change. If you simply change the geometry of the view, the view is typically not redrawn. Instead, its existing content is adjusted based on the value in the view’s contentMode property. Redisplaying the existing content improves performance by avoiding the need to redraw content that has not changed.

Comment: Unfortunately my drawRect code is already a custom view (Extends UIView) rather than being in the UITableViewCell...  Edited the question to clarify that... 
I'll try invalidating to get it to re-draw, but I thought that would cause severe performance issues...

Comment: That's a good thing. Have you tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` on that view right after you tell your cell what style (left or right) it should be?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I don't think, that overriding `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` is the right resolution for your problem. My advice would be to override it  **only** if you **exactly** know what are you doing and what are you trying to achieve.

According to images, you have provided, the problem you are facing is related with `UITableViewCell` reusing, but not with the drawing.

**The problem.** When table view scrolling hits the boundary of `UITableView` to present new content, `UITableView` doesn't create a new cell instance. It takes the currently invisible cell (the one which has been to scrolled out to present new one on screen) and reuses it (`UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DialogCell"];`). In your example, lines of code executed after the cell is being reused only sets the cell content text up. From the images you provided, I see, that the text is sat up correctly. The problem is with cells background. Since there is not a single line of code to setup cells background after it is being reused, background before reuse is being presented.

**Recommendations.** Obviously, you need to override cells background each time it is being reused. If I were you, I would create a subclass of class `UITableViewCell`, lets say `MyTableViewCell`. The cell would have a method like:

```
- (void)setupWithSide:(Side)side {
    if (side == SideRight) {
        [self setupRightAlignedCintent];
        [self setupLeftBackground];
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, in `UITableViewController` you have to

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DialogCell"];

    Side side;

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        side = SideRight;
    } else {
        side = SideLeft;
    }

    [cell setupWithSide:side];

    return cell;
}
```